# How can I show data from my personal API to a gauge dashboard without a DB?

Tags: python, json, api, datasource, grafana

I’m new here and I’m trying to learn as good as how to use Grafana for University IoT project. I’m written an API that returns data from a gyroscope. I want to use grafana to show live data into a dashboard but without using a database: I’m using JSON to send data from server to client but I don’t know how can show it. Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- Adapt your application backend service to support API for [Simple JSON Datasource](https://github.com/grafana/simple-json-datasource) (look at numerous implementations of it on Github for examples).
- Install `simple-json-datasource` plugin in Grafana and setup it to use your application's API endpoint.